# Vias not visible after Eagle Cam Processor

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, eaglecad

I am trying to generate a printout of the PCB using Eagle Cam processor to get it made.

My settings are as follows:

1. Section: *
2. Device: PS
3. Style: pos. Coord and Fill pads are enabled
4. Layers: top, pads and vias for the top; bottom, pads and vias for the bottom

Unfortunately, my vias/holes are not visible in the output file. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Disabling Fill pads solves the problem.